# URL Sharing from Google plus

Tags: url, web, query-string, share, google-plus

How can I share a URL with a link using Google+ like:

Facebook

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://google.com
```

Twitter

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://google.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://google.com
```

See official documentation for more details: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink